Inner join of the same table without duplicates for certain values
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  key BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (10, true);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (11, true);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (12, true);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (20, false);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (21, false);

I wanted only values with id equal to 11 or 12:
SELECT my_table_1.id,
       my_table_1.key,
       my_table_2.id,
       my_table_2.key
FROM my_table AS my_table_1
  INNER JOIN my_table AS my_table_2 
    ON my_table_1.id < my_table_2.id
      AND my_table_1.key = my_table_2.key
      AND my_table_1.id IN (11, 12)

Instead of the full result:



my_table_1.id
my_table_1.key
my_table_2.id
my_table_2.key




10
t
11
t


10
t
12
t


11
t
12
t



I got a wrong partial result:



my_table_1.id
my_table_1.key
my_table_2.id
my_table_2.key




11
t
12
t



I figured out how to get the full result with double IN:
SELECT my_table_1.id,
       my_table_1.key,
       my_table_2.id,
       my_table_2.key
FROM my_table AS my_table_1
  INNER JOIN my_table AS my_table_2 
    ON my_table_1.id < my_table_2.id
      AND my_table_1.key = my_table_2.key
      AND (my_table_1.id IN (11, 12) OR my_table_2.id IN (11, 12))

Which gives me the correct result.
Another example with id IN (21):
SELECT my_table_1.id,
       my_table_1.key,
       my_table_2.id,
       my_table_2.key
FROM my_table AS my_table_1
  INNER JOIN my_table AS my_table_2 
    ON my_table_1.id < my_table_2.id
      AND my_table_1.key = my_table_2.key
      AND (my_table_1.id IN (21) OR my_table_2.id IN (21))

This also gives the correct result:



my_table_1.id
my_table_1.key
my_table_2.id
my_table_2.key




20
f
21
f



Without the second IN, I would have got an empty result.
How can I improve this query?
I don't like using the IN twice.
On the small amount data there's no problem. A problem appears on the real data, when e.g. 10000 ids is queried, and instead of one monstrous list of ids, there are two monstrous lists of ids.

Why do you put one join condition in the ON clause, and another in the WHERE clause?

@jarlh Updated queries with moving condition by your suggestion. Thanks!

All of your queries are missing commas in the SELECT list. Even when that is corrected, the first two example query results don't match the results returned by the corresponding query. The example desired output is not a subset of the results of the first unfiltered query and doesn't match the results of the query with two IN expressions. These inconsistencies make it impossible to ascertain the intended behavior. Please update the post to address the inconsistences and provide a more detailed explanation of the question the query is intended to answer.

@MichaelLinker I agree with JohnH's comment and don't understand what you want to do. Could you please simplify and improve your question? It should clearly show sample input data and the expected result and explain what logic should be applied.

Use UNION/UNION ALL instead of OR, but still we need to understand what are you trying to achieve

@JohnH Thanks, I simplified the question a bit and corrected the queries. I also added the original queries.

@JonasMetzler My, thanks! I just want to simplify final query, but save the correct result :)
The original data and queries have been updated.

What's the problem with your query? Maybe you could use GREATEST(my_table_1.id, my_table_2.id) IN (11,12) if you dislike the second IN clause.

@JonasMetzler On the small amount data there's no problem. Problem appears on the real data, when e.g. 10000 ids was queried, and instead of one monstrous list of ids, there are two monstrous lists of ids in the SQL query.

@JonasMetzler Do I understand correctly that two conditions with IN need to collapse into one with GREATEST?

Please see here what I mean. If your id's you want to check are numeric in a range or in some ranges, you could furthermore use BETWEEN rather than IN. For example maybe ...BETWEEN 10 and 20 or ...BETWEEN 50 and 60 rather than IN (11,12,....,19,20,50,51,...,59,60)

@JonasMetzler Yeah, thanks, I have tested your suggestion. Although the query plan remained the same, but it was possible to significantly reduce the monstrosity of the query, thank you!
Unfortunately, such a large amount of ids cannot be ordered and replaced with BETWEEN, because they are submitted in random order, so I have to dynamically build a list of ids for the real query.

I don't think you will observe any important changes in the query plan because your query seems ok to me, although it might be unpleasant to fill the list of ids. Another idea would be to use another column or a mapping table to save the relevant ids and join that table in your query, thus you might get rid of the lists.

maybe insert all these IDs into a temp table then just query against that.

@Randy Provide example please. Are you talking about CTE?

For Reduce multiple list if Ids Can use CTE like this

    WITH IDs AS (
        SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id IN (11, 12) 
    )
    SELECT my_table_1.id,
           my_table_1.key,
           my_table_2.id,
           my_table_2.key
    FROM my_table AS my_table_1
      INNER JOIN my_table AS my_table_2
        ON my_table_1.id < my_table_2.id
          AND my_table_1.key = my_table_2.key
          AND (my_table_1.id IN (SELECT id FROM IDs)
               OR my_table_2.id IN (SELECT id FROM IDs))
    ORDER BY my_table_2.id
    


Is it possible to replace a double SELECT with single JOIN?

Yes with Left join ->
WITH IDs AS (
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id IN (11, 12)
)
SELECT my_table_1.id,
my_table_1.key,
my_table_2.id,
my_table_2.key
FROM my_table AS my_table_1
INNER JOIN my_table AS my_table_2
ON my_table_1.id < my_table_2.id
AND my_table_1.key = my_table_2.key
LEFT JOIN IDs AS ids_1
ON my_table_1.id = ids_1.id
LEFT JOIN IDs AS ids_2
ON my_table_2.id = ids_2.id
WHERE ids_1.id IS NOT NULL OR ids_2.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY my_table_2.id
